# How stringstream works?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm using `stringstream` type variable in my program.
following is code snippet:

```
stringstream keyvalueStream;
keyvalueStream << // appending some string 

somefun(keyvalueStream.str().c_str()); // Passing the char*
keyvalueStream.str(std::string()); // clearing the content of this variable.
```

Does clearing the content of `keyvalueStream` affect the string that I will get in the `somefun()`?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question depends on what `somefun` does with the `char const *` you've passed to it, and not on whether or not you clear the contents of the `stringstream`.

[`stringstream::str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) returns an `std::string` object *by value*, so it's irrelevant whether you clear the `stringstream` contents later on or not.

In the expression

```
somefun(keyvalueStream.str().c_str());
```

the returned `string` object will be destroyed when the call to `somefun` returns. Hence, if `somefun` somehow stores the `char const *` for later use, you will have undefined behavior. If it operates on the argument however it needs to in the current function call, your code is safe.

Answer (score 0):

When reaching keyvalueStream.str(std::string()); in your snippet somefun(keyvalueStream.str().c_str()); has already finished executing, so no. If that was your question.

Answer (score 0):

No it wont affect what you have passed into somefun() already. stringstream::str() return by value so you get a copy of the data in your stream, not a reference to it.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The object dies only afte `somefun` returns (end of full expression)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It will.

However you shouldn't even call the `c_str()` once you get the underlying `str`. It is available till the end of the expression.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str),

> **Notes**
>
> The copy of the underlying string returned by str is a temporary object that will be destructed at the end of the expression, so directly calling c_str() on the result of str() (for example in auto *ptr = out.str().c_str();) results in a dangling pointer.

Comment: So what should i do in my case? any suggestion? above ans says that it won't affect?

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to say whether or not the OP should be calling `c_str` on the returned string.

Comment: -1, the "end of the expression" is after `somefun` returns which is late enough. The example you quote from `cppreference` doesn't apply to this question.